# How to remove the line "Received; acceped" from title?

Tags: lyx, titles, templates

I am using the `aastex.lyx` template to write an article and I cannot find a way to remove the "Received; -------- Accepted" line coming after the title.
Does anyone know how to remove it ?

Answer (score 6):

Looking into `aastex.cls`, the macro responsible for typesetting "Received/Accepted" is `\@dates` with the following definition:

```
\def\@dates{\ifx\@title\@empty\else {Received}\space%
 \ifx\@empty\@recvdate\@rcvaccrule\else\@recvdate\fi;%
 \hspace{1.5em}{accepted}\space%
 \ifx\@empty\@accptdate\@rcvaccrule\else\@accptdate\fi%
\fi}%                                                 %
```

Disabling `\@dates` seems to do the trick.

```
\documentclass{aastex}

\makeatletter
\let\@dates\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{(Author)}
\title{(Title)}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

As you're using LyX, you have to add the code lines from `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` into your LaTeX preamble.

Comment: @EdgarHemery You may also thank me by accepting my answer (and upvoting it as soon as you have 15 rep).